# Is there any difference between the terms 'define' and 'qualify'?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

I have looked up their etymologies but cannot come to a nuanced demarcation between the terms. I know both generally imply limiting of a concept; in the case of 'qualify', extending to general statements as well. 'Define' etymologically means to end or finish completely. Ironically, I cannot seem to qualify/define 'qualify'.

Comment: _Define_ can mean _mark the boundaries of_, but its main meaning is _state the nature or meaning of_. In what sense do you want to use these words?

Comment: You can define something, and then qualify that definition.

Comment: In the sense that if I want to ask about a concept like gravity. Can it be both, define/qualify gravity? Thanks @KateBunting

Comment: What does it mean to qualify a definition? Isn't a definition by definition(sorry) qualified? Thanks @WeatherVane

Comment: Well, one example might be where some Terms & Conditions specify that something must be notified **in writing**, which is defined in small print as, say, "by means of pen on paper or typeface ink on paper and communicated by mail or by hand". But along comes electronic communication and the definition of "in writing" needs to be **qualified** to include email, which was not envisaged earlier. The same could be true of any definition, which when examined closely, needs to be qualified for particular circumstances.

Comment: The only definition of _qualify_ that seems relevant is _make (a statement or assertion) less absolute; add reservations to_..